# how to check multiple return values

Tags: python

I am tryign to check if any of the values "GIN" or "NOT READY" or "TO BE ABANDON OR NEEDS RESUBMISSION" equals retrunVal,i notice that for any returnVal the "if" loop" is getting and "INSIDE" is getting printed,I am doubting the syntax is not right,can anyone provide inputs?

```
    if ('GIN'  or 'NOT READY' or 'TO BE ABANDON OR NEEDS RESUBMISSION' == returnVal):
        print "INSIDE"
```

Answer (score 8):

Like this:

```
if returnValue in ('GIN', 'NOT READY', 'TO BE ABANDON OR NEEDS RESUBMISSION'):
    print 'INSIDE'
```

That's the standard idiom - using the `in` operator to test membership in a tuple with all possible values. Much cleaner than a bunch of `or`'ed contitions.

Answer (score 6):

Your code, logically, reads like this:

```
if 'GIN' exists
or if 'NOT READY' exists
or if 'TO BE ABANDON OR NEEDS RESUBMISSION' is equal to retVal
   do something
```

Read this [link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) about truth-values in python (this is also related to paxdiablo's answer).

a better approach is to use python's "in" statement:

```
if retVal in ['GIN', 'NOT READY', 'TO BE ABANDON OR NEEDS RESUBMISSION']:
   do something
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it:

```
if (returnVal == 'GIN')  or (returnVal == 'NOT READY') or returnVal == '...':
```

though a more Pythonic better way would be to use `in`:

```
if returnVal in ['GIN', 'NOT READY', '...']:
```

In other words (for that first case), use *separate* conditions and just `or` them together.

The reason you're always seeing `INSIDE` is because `'GIN'` is a effectively being treated as a `true` value in the context of a conditional:

```
>>> if 'GIN':
...     print "yes"
... 
yes
```

and `true or <anything>` is `true`.